# ASP.NET authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I develop some site, that uses authentication ticket from API of other service.
I have method GetSessionTicket() from API. And now question:
can i do asp.net authentication thats depends only from cookie?
Now i remove all section about Membership provider at web.config:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>-->
<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

and left this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

LogOn logic looks like:

```
var ticket = SecurityService.GetSessionTicket(model.UserName, model.Password);
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(ticket.SessionUserId.ToString(), true);
```

Is it ok? Now my ASP.NET authorization based only on cookie and does not require sql server or aspnetdb.mdf, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is fine to do this, what you are essentially doing is implementing **Forms** authentication, without the membership database.  You are not required to use a membership datbase to achieve authentication, and setting the cookies in code is fine.